# pt-online-schema-change failed when creating new tablle, specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes issue

Tags: mysql, innodb, percona, percona-toolkit

The version, mysql is InnoDB 5.6.10-log, pt-online-schema-change 3.1.0. table info is

```
`email` varchar(225) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`uid` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`hotel_brand_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,

UNIQUE KEY `index_membership_customers_on_uid_and_hotel_brand_id` (`uid`,`hotel_brand_id`),
```

My purpose is to add a unique index,

```
pt-online-schema-change --recursion-method=none --nocheck-unique-key-change h=$DATABASE_HOST,D=$DATABASE,t=$TABLE,u=$DATABASE_USER,p=$DATABASE_PASSWORD   --alter "ADD UNIQUE INDEX index_membership_customers_on_email_and_hotel_brand_id (email, hotel_brand_id)"   --$RUN --alter-foreign-keys-method=auto
```

then I met the unique index length issue(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814532/mysql-error-1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes),

```
Creating new table...
Error creating new table: DBD::mysql::db do failed: Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes [for Statement "CREATE TABLE `umami_prod`.`_membership_customers_new` (
```

It seems this was the cause

```
`uid` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY `index_membership_customers_on_uid_and_hotel_brand_id` (`uid`,`hotel_brand_id`)
```

so I want to resize the columns or change its character set, but whatever I got to do,
it failed because `pt-online-schema-change` try to create a new table first, then it failed because of this index length issue in the beginning. I couldn't change anything

So my question is

1. How does the current table support this utfm8 varchar(255), How does it possible?

```
UNIQUE KEY `index_membership_customers_on_uid_and_hotel_brand_id` (`uid`,`hotel_brand_id`)
```

2. Maybe there are table settings I missed for `pt-online-schema-change`
3. Anything I couldn't do, next, it is a 4M rows size table, and since `pt-online-schema-change` couldn't work because of the above issue, my only option is alter, to lock whole table?

Thanks for your reply, any hint might help, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can you live with 191 instead of 225?  If not, your 5 options (including that one) are here:

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes

Comment: Ya, I am ok `191 instead of 225`, I couldn't, because the current problem is, that it would fail when executing `pt-online-schema-change`, so it seems I need to ask for maintenance to lock the table.